# Why $PGL(2, 9)$ is not isomorphic to $S_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, linear-groups

> How can I show that $PGL(2,9)$ is not isomorphic to $S_6$?

My primary idea is to compare the size of conjugacy classes of two well-chosen elements in these groups. Is there another simpler approach?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please share your thoughts on this problem or you will have a difficult time receiving answers. :)

Comment: @DonLarynx I add some of my ideas to edited version. Also I found another simpler approach. But what can we say about conjugacy classes?Is my primary idea mentioned in question works?

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way to prove two finite groups are different than comparing sizes of subsets with algebraic significance.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat You're right. Let me ask my question in another form : Finding a well-chosen element(s) that could conclude the non-isomorphism makes me lots of thinking and computings! Is there any known strategy that help us to find these well-chosen "subsets with algebraic significance"?

Comment: I don't think there is a general strategy, but what works, and helps foster a good understanding of the particularities of the group at hand, is concrete calculations. With groups arising from linear transformation groups, you can always use the the theory of endomorphisms of vector spaces : Jordan canonical form, minimal and characteristic polynomials to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a generator of group $\mathbb F^*_9$. Now if consider the matrix $A=\hbox{diag}(1, \alpha)$ in $PGL(2,9)$ we have $\hbox{ord}(A)=8$, since $\hbox{ord}(\alpha)=8$. But there isn't any element of order $8$ in the symmetric group $S_6$. So these two groups can not be isomorphic.